# PayPal CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile Billing frequency

Tags: paypal, recurring-billing

I have manage to get my site to work with paypal billing CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile however I am confused regarding the fields of

BILLINGPERIOD & BILLINGFREQUENCY

If I set first to Monthly and second to 12 hoping it would charge my customers each month I get this is email:
"Billing cycle:Every 12 Months"
Is this correct?

What if I want it to charge daily? I tried doing 'Day' and '365' and it said billing cycle 365 days which sounds to me like after every year.

I couldn't find anything clear in the documentation as well so kindly direct me. Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're on the right track. From the [PayPal docs](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECRecurringPayments):

> Make one payment per billing cycle. Each billing cycle has 2
>   components:
>
> - The billing period specifies the unit to calculate the billing cycle    (such as days or months).
> - The billing frequency specifies the number    of billing periods that make up the billing cycle.
>
> For example, if the billing period is Month and the billing frequency
>   is 2, the billing cycle is 2 months. If the billing period is Week and
>   the billing frequency is 6, PayPal schedules the payments every 6
>   weeks.

In your stated example, setting `BILLINGPERIOD` to `Monthly` and `BILLINGFREQUENCY` to `12` will schedule payments *once every 12 months*.

To schedule payments *once each month*, you must set `BILLINGPERIOD` to `Monthly` and `BILLINGFREQUENCY` to `1`.

Similarly, to schedule payments *daily*, you must set `BILLINGPERIOD` to `Day` and `BILLINGFREQUENCY` to `1`.

Comment: And to limit it to 12 billings every 1 months, set TOTALBILLINGCYCLES=12, BILLINGPERIOD=Month, BILLINGFREQUENCY=1

Comment: Thanks Josh, Just one question, the doc also said something like billingperiod and billingfrequency should not exceed one year, what's that supposed to mean.

Comment: Robert, do you mean limit billings to one year?  Because '12 billings every 1 month' doesn't make sense. Thanks

Comment: @UsmanZaheer This means, for instance, you cannot have `BILLINGPERIOD` set to `Monthly` and `BILLINGFREQUENCY` set to `13` (greater than 1 year), or `BILLINGPERIOD` set to `Day` and `BILLINGFREQUENCY` set to `366` (greater than 1 year). Do those examples help?

Comment: Took me a while to get this, but this is necessary because of how date math works.  For example some months are not always 30 days.  February is 28 days sometimes and others 29.  So if you wanted to bill someone every 3 months you HAVE to know a frequency and a billing period so it knows how to calculate correctly.  Hope this helps someone understand it better.

Comment: BILLINGPERIOD should be Month, not Monthly

Comment: sorry for asking here but i have question: If i set `BILLINGPERIOD=Month`, `BILLINGFREQUENCY=1` and `TOTALBILLINGCYCLES=0` then i can billed every month until the profile is canceled or deactivated correct?